# when using opengauss, i can't select my data

Tags: open-gauss

I have a table, and I already have some data in it.
But when I select from the table, it said "failed to decrypt column encryption key".
why?

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llPUy.png)

Answer (score 0):

May the client does not have client master key
you can check the CMK environment variables.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

about openGauss ，This could be due to the column encryption key not being properly configured. Check to ensure that the encryption key is valid and that you have the correct permissions to access it. Additionally, make sure that the encryption key is up-to-date and has been backed up properly.